# Can you remove an object from an Array by its object condition and not by index?

Tags: java

I've been learning about Java Arrays lately and I'm practicing doing some kind of inventory or pouch where you store, remove and exchange objects.

But I would like to know if there's a way to, for example, remove an object for being that object and not because is in a determinated index in the list...

I have this class with a constructor, that assigns 2 properties: 'Nombre' (name of the object) and adicion (an int, since this could be used in a game we can say this is the number of hp you recover by using a potion)

```
public class Objetos {
    String nombre;
    int adicion;
    public void objetos(String nomb, int sumar){
        adicion = sumar;
        nombre = nomb;
    }

  public void setNombre (String nomb){
        nombre = nomb;
    }

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }  


  public void setAdicion (int sumar){
        adicion = sumar;
    }

    public int getAdicion(){
        return adicion;
    }
}
```

Then, I have this array of objects:

```
static Objetos[] objetos_inv = new Objetos[15];
objetos_inv[0] = new Objetos();
objetos_inv[0].nombre = "Potion";
objetos_inv[0].adicion = 20;
System.out.println(objetos_inv[0]);
```

I added an object, and now of course I can remove, change or print it by his index position (0), but what If I don't know (is happening 100%) the index where a object is going to be placed? I can remove it for being a "potion"?

I'm just learning, probably have a lot of misconceptions, sorry If I said or assume something dumb. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: So with the term "remove an object for being that object and not because is in a determinated index in the list" you mean delete an object because of specific values in some member variables?

Comment: Exactly, thank you, I'm not native and sometimes is hard to find the exact words if we are on a specific context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer: No**

In order to remove an element from an array (**no matter what type of array**) **you should know** the index of the element you want to remove/edit.

**Workarounds for your case**

**1) In case you have the reference of the object you want to delete**

**i) Use an implementation of the  [List class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (f.e [Arraylist)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) to store your objects**

So when you have the reference of the object you can remove it by using

```
objetosList.remove(objectToBeDeleted);
```

**ii) Use commons lang's ArrayUtils in your array**

```
ArrayUtils.removeElement(objetos_inv, objectToBeDeleted);
```

**2) In case you do not have the reference of the object you should make a search in your array, by values to get the index of the object you need and then use that index for any further actions.**

```
private Objetos findObjetoByNombre(Objetos[] objetos, String nombre){
   for(Objetos objeto: objetos){
      if(objeto.getNombre().equals(nombre){
         return objeto;
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Non related directly but you know why my constructor doesn't require arguments? I'm trying to create a new object like this                                                             `Objetos potion = new Objetos();` and if I enter values it says that.

Comment: In your example you are using the no-arguments (default) constructor, you can create as much unique constructors you want using any member variables of the class. All IDEs have ways to generate them. 

example

`public Objectos(String nombre){ this.nombre = nombre; } `

and call it with `Objeto objeto = new Object("your_value");`

Comment: When I create the object `Objetos potion = new Objetos("Potion", 20);`, and add it to my Array with `objetos_inv.add(potion);` if I try to `System.out.println(objetos_inv)` I get a null output

Comment: This is a  separate question, for the better understanding of the question by the community please post a new question with what you have dones in detail and send the link :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058591/getting-null-output-from-array here it is, thank you in advance and sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want to do, but if you want a "collection" (such as an array) of object and you want to get the one you need by the object and not an index you should look to [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

Of maybe just an arrayList should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use commons lang's ArrayUtils.

array = ArrayUtils.removeElement(array, element)
Here you can check the element and call a method to remove the element

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your description I think what you need is a Map. You want store many Objetos objects and access it by the value of "nombre" variable.

Try to use a Hashmap:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Objetos objetos = new Objetos();
        objetos.setNombre("Potion");
        objetos.setAdicion(1);

        Map<String, Objetos> objetosMap = new HashMap();
        objetosMap.put(objetos.getNombres(), objetos);
    }
```

Now you can access your Objetos objects in the map by their `nombre` value.