# Getting null output from Array

Tags: java

I'm trying to print an Array filled with some objects and I'm getting a null output.

The array is in my Main class for scope needs

```java
public class Main {
   static ArrayList<Objetos> objetos_inv = new ArrayList<Objetos>();
```

In another class, where I want to add, retrieve and print the array and his objects:

```java
public class ModoHistoria {
static Objetos potion = new Objetos("Potion", 20);
    public static void modoHistoria(){
       for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
       }
    System.out.println(objetos_inv);
    }
```

variables of my `Objetos` class are `nombre` and `adicion`:

```java
public class Objetos {
    static String nombre;
    static int adicion;
    public Objetos (String nombre, int adicion){
        adicion = adicion;
        nombre = nombre;
    }

  public void setNombre (String nombre){
        nombre = nombre;
    }

      @Override
    public String toString() {
    return nombre;  
}

    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }  


  public void setAdicion (int adicion){
        adicion = adicion;
    }

    public int getAdicion(){
        return adicion;
    }


}
```

Output:

```
[null, null]
```

Comment: @DushyantTankariya no, he should print objetos_inv.get(index);

Comment: Yes, but still he may needs to print the object by giving a specific class property...

Comment: @DushyantTankariya only if there is no `toString` method. And even then, it would not print `null`, and it should not be only two.

Comment: @C.Roma why are you increment `i` two times? the first one in the loop `for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){` and second in the loop body `objetos_inv.add(potion); i++;` ?

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc I didn't notice, just souldn't be there.

Comment: Please add a [MCVE]. What is `Objetos`? Also please run your code with a debugger and check what actually is in your `objetos_inv`. Don't just rely on a print output. We have no idea to tell if those objects actually are `null` or if their `toString` method returns `null`. But you can tell the difference and should actually tell us in your question.

Comment: @RealSkeptic toString method is already Overrided in Objetos Class to prevent irregular output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Objetos (String nombre, int adicion){
    adicion = adicion;
    nombre = nombre;
}
```

This doesn't set your class members. `adicion` and `nombre` are local to that constructor. If you want it to set the members of the object, you need to use `this`:

```
public Objetos (String nombre, int adicion){
    this.adicion = adicion;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

Please learn how to use your debugger. You can step through your code line by line while it's running and look at all values and objects to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stultuske said you need `objetos_inv.get(index)` to get the particular object and also you need to use the class property to get exact value you want to print.

I've prepared a small demo which helps you to understand how you'll able to print the correct output.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloWorld{
    static List<Objectos> objetos_inv = new ArrayList<Objectos>();
    static Objectos potion = new Objectos("Potion", 20);
    public static void main(String []args){
        modoHistoria();    
    }

    public static void modoHistoria(){
        objetos_inv.add(potion);
        System.out.println(objetos_inv.get(0).getNombre());
        // Or you have override toString() as @RealSkeptic mentioned in his comment So you can also directly print.
        System.out.println(objetos_inv.get(0));
    }

}
class Objectos{

    private String nombre;
    private int adicion;

    public Objectos(){};
    public Objectos(String nombre, int adicion){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.adicion = adicion;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getNombre(){
        return nombre;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setAdicion(int adicion){
        this.adicion = adicion;
    }
    public int getAdicion(){
        return adicion;
    }
}
```

And also agreed with a @MaxVollmer answer regarding set your class members.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, It does not make any sense to initialize static members in constructor.Instead use a static initializer to initialize it as this is common for all instances of the class.

```
static {  
     nombre = "Potion";
}
```

Comment: Good catch, but I am pretty sure OP actually does *not* want those to be static.